# Building route along specific roads

Tags: here-api

I am going to build a route along some specified roads.

For example:
Is it possible to build a route using HERE Routes API along Interstate 80?

Comment: if you have waypoints then Route Import might be the right one for you to do it. https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/route-import.html

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport , The problem is that even if I have enough points along the road, most often I wont need them all. In the most cases, the route will cover only a part of the specified road

Comment: Dear User, Could you share your use-case, so that we could assist better.